# xcode llvm 5.0 error no such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, llvm

I have this error displaying, the LLVM APPlE 5.0 ANY IDEAS? 
i have also cleaned, deleted the derived data, checked the scroll view delegate methods, checked the prefix in build settings and the build phases

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/zoe/Documents/PROJECT /TapADogNEW copy 2/TapADogNEW/TapADogNEW/TapADogNEW-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: As suggested please check if your pre complied header file "TapADogNEW-Prefix.pch" is in you project!

Answer (score 2):

The reason is described in error message: It can't find ***.pch** file:
Check target settings and set correct path to prefix header file:
[image: Project settings]

Answer (score 0):

I get this error in Xcode 6 anytime I rename a file.

Normally in Xcode 5 I would rename a project, but that doesn't work in Xcode 6.

I have to go back to the original name, because it doesn't change the name in all the correct locations.

Submitted a bug report: 19086479

Answer (score 0):

I just created the pch file from File->NewFile->Other->pch file and replaced the oldone. After that project was build successfully